# Can phonegap use canvas?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, canvas

I am new in programming phonegap using javascript!
I am try to use canvas in my project but it's didn't work!
This is my code:
index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {

}
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look like you are trying to access the mycanvas element before it actually exists in the document (since it appears after your code).  Move your code into the deviceready function or just move it below the canvas element.

Comment: What @Imortenson suggested is correct. Before trying to get this to run in Phonegap, get it to run in Chrome first. Checking console immediately shows you there is an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null`

Comment: Thanks alot! i fixed it! :D. take script below to fix this problem! :D thanks all